# XSL 1.0 - sort a list from a different list

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

i'm new with XSL and have tried to look through all the examples on here but none match my problem.

i have a sort order list of movies (order from left to right)

```
<movies>movieF,movieC,movieG</movies>
```

now i want to take that sort order list and sort on top of this huge movies list of mine

```
<moviesList>
 <movie>movieA</movie>
 <movie>movieB</movie>
 <movie>movieC</movie>
 <movie>movieD</movie>
 <movie>movieE</movie>
 <movie>movieF</movie>
 <movie>movieG</movie>
 <movie>movieH</movie>
</moviesList>
```

result i want:

```
<moviesList>
 <movie>movieF</movie>
 <movie>movieC</movie>
 <movie>movieG</movie>
 <movie>movieA</movie>
 <movie>movieB</movie>
 <movie>movieD</movie>
 <movie>movieE</movie>
 <movie>movieH</movie>
</moviesList>
```

would someone please give me some guidance of how to achieve such thing. i've tried to create a variable $sortlist, and then add delimited character around and then use substring-before trick on the sort. result is my sorted list did show up on top before the rest of the movies but it's not on the right order. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="sortlist" select="';movieF;movieC;movieG;'"/>

  <xsl:template match="moviesList">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each select="*[contains($sortlist, concat(';',.,';'))]">
        <xsl:sort select="substring-before($sortlist,concat(';',.,';'))" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[not(contains($sortlist, concat(';',.,';')))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice, I didn't use `string-length` to sort, I just used the string itself. XSLT1.0 can sort alphabetically instead of numerically, which would place 14 above 7, resulting in the order movieF, movieG, movieC.

It actually uses the portion of the list of movie names that comes before each one as the sort key; alphabetically speaking, `;movieF;` comes before `;movieF;movieC;`, therefore it'll place `movieC` above `movieG` when sorting.

Personally I tend to avoid using commas as a separator as they can be used in some names, such as 'Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon'. A semicolon's far less likely, but you could use any character you like as long as it's not one that appears in a movie name.